# Can someone explain the conversion from byte array to hexadecimal string in java

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte

I was recently looking for an encoding to convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string. 
For one, I found the following from: [how to convert hex to byte for the following program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555503/how-to-convert-hex-to-byte-for-the-following-program)

I have already tried this:

```
StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer(cipherbyte.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherbyte.length; i++) {
        if ((cipherbyte[i] & 0xff) < 0x10 ) {
            stringbuffer.append("0");
        }
        stringbuffer.append(Long.toString(cipherbyte[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    String ciphertext = stringbuffer.toString();
    return ciphertext;
```

for decoding:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[message.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i = i+2) {
        String substr = message.substring(i, i+2);
        bytes[i/2] = ((byte) Integer.parseInt(substr, 16));
    }
```

but I dont kow how these algorithms work in detail, please can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create a StringBuffer to hold the ciphertext. Maximum you need double its size if all the byte is 0x0 and 0x9 
StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer(cipherbyte.length * 2);


    for (int i = 0; i < cipherbyte.length; i++) { // get each byte
        if ((cipherbyte[i] & 0xff) < 0x10 ) {  // if byte is between 0x0 and 0x9, padding a 0
            stringbuffer.append("0");
        }
        // get current byte as long type and convert into a 16 radix string.
        // this combine the code above if byte is between 0x0 and 0x9
        stringbuffer.append(Long.toString(cipherbyte[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }


    String ciphertext = stringbuffer.toString();
    return ciphertext;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still little bit confuse with the substring for decoding. `String substr = message.substring(i, i+2);`

Comment: decode just the reverse of the encode. It get 2 char each time and parse it as a radius 16 integer==>covert to the byte==>save it into the byte array "bytes". For the same reason above for encode, but the decode need exactly length/2 to hold all the bytes.